# How to output bibliography as \bibitem{bate}

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing final year thesis in undergraduate.

I have already have xx.bib, like

```
@article{Ahmad2012,
author = {Ahmad, Imtiaz and Higgins, Peter M},
file = {:home/peng/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/ahmadIMF25-28-2012.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {among all graph labelling,attracted the most attention,bandwidth numbering,bandwidth of products of,cylinder,graph,graphs,in the literature,introduction,of graphs has perhaps,problems,rectangular lattice,the,toroidal graph},
mendeley-groups = {FYP},
number = {27},
pages = {1331--1341},
title = {{Bandwidth of Direct Products of Paths and Cycles}},
volume = {7},
year = {2012}
}
```

I want to output bibliography, like

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{bate}   Bates, R.A.,  R.F. Buck, E. Riccomagno and
H.P. Wynn (1996). Expimental design and observation for large
systems, \emph{J. Roy. Statist. Soc. Ser. B}, 58, 77-94. \ \ \\
 \end{thebibliography}
```

I have tried compile xx.bib, but do not find the output like above.
What should I do?

Comment: Usually you do this by including `\cite` commands in your text and a `\bibliographystyle{<bib-style>}` command.  The command `\bibliography{<your-bib-file>}` is put where you want the bibliography to go.  Then you compile your file with latex, bibtex, latex, latex.  Have you done that?

Comment: Have you tried using the `makebst` utililty, which is entirely menu driven, to create your own custom bibliography style? Incidentally, the `apalike` bibliography style will do all of the required formatting elements you describe except for (i) inverting the ordering of first and last names for authors 2 through n and (ii) placing a comma after the volume number.

Comment: I tried and get the bibliography. However, I have a new problem: it does not appear "Chung 1987[1]",it appear only "1".

Comment: And I want to list all bibliography at the end of the page, although I do not point out some of the reference. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: The problem of formating results from unapprioate choice of `.bst` style file.  
And the output of the whole bibliography  without `\cite` can be produced withe the command `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: @JohnHass -- the information you gave in your question was not enough for readers here to reproduce your problem or experiment.  the item from the `.bib` file does not match the `\bibitem`.  the members of this group have given their best guesses, but all you added was a "new problem", with no detail.  the request for news was simply a request for you to modify your question into something that we can work with.  if that doesn't happen, the question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I thought someone also got the problem as I had 3 years ago. Please close, thanks.